# posting protobuf message into HTTP request body using in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, protocol-buffers

I have generated set of java files from .proto files using gradle's protobuf plugin for java. And i've also generated message object using that. Now how can i submit protobuf's byte stream in HTTP POST method's request body.

```
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    HttpEntity<byte[]> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestObject.toByteArray(), httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> response =
        _restTemplate.exchange("https://example.com/xyz", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

But i am getting error

`org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request`